# How to control which application opens a jpg image stored on a smartphone connected to Windows 7 via USB?

Tags: windows, usb, images, file-association, smartphone

In Windows 7, when I open a jpg image on local storage, it opens in the app specified by Windows' file associations (stored in the Windows Registry).

When I open the same file when it is stored on a smartphone attached via USB, the image is always opened in Windows Photo Viewer.

Why is this, and how can it be changed?